# Security fails in private key and xor

Tags: encryption, audit

I've implemented a very short program to encrypt a file, and send it on a remote server. First, I build a key based on a pass-phrase and a subset of prime numbers (the length of the key is defined by the user, 100KB by default). Encryption is made of a simple XOR from source's bytes and "modulated bytes" of the key, eg: `s ^ k`. An index of the files is sent, crypted too.

If the private key, and the private pass-phrase are never sent to the server, is it possible to decrypt files, file type or names ?

This is the code of the encryption when the key was generated.

```
while (!feof(fp_src))
{
    v = fgetc(fp_src) ;
    if (v == EOF) { break ; } // Success : end of process.

    // Loop on key content :
    p = fgetc(fp_key) ;
    if (p == EOF) {
        fseek(fp_key, 0, SEEK_SET) ;
        p = fgetc(fp_key) ;
        if (p == EOF) { break ; }
    }

    o = v ^ p ;
    fputc(o, fp_out) ;

    show_progress(src_len, proc_idx) ;
    proc_idx++ ;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "and a subset of the prime numbers" ​ literal face-palm ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: The first rule of crypto club is don't talk about crypto club. Na I'm kidding. It's don't roll your own crypto.

Comment: There is a reason simply XORing bytes together isn't used as an encryption scheme today...  I feel I ask this all the time but why can you not just use AES...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you're doing a [one time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) - but it's actually a multi-time pad because the key is finite (< 100kb) and derived from a passphrase.

Breaking (aka cryptanalysing) this would be fun! Here's some things I would start with:

1. You say the key is derived from a passphrase. You don't tell us how in your question, but if I had access to your binary then I could reverse engineer it to figure that out. From there I can try a dictionary of common passphrases until I get a ciphertext that matches - then I know what your key is (this is a form of [chosen-plaintext attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack)).
2. Frequency analysis: since I know you're looping over the key XORing each byte of the key multiple times (and presumably always starting with the first byte of the key for a new massage), I can count how often each byte of key produces each ciphertext character. The most common char of ciphertext (for each byte of key) must map to the letter 'e', which will let me figure out the entire key. Not knowing the length of the key makes this more difficult - but certainly not impossible.

---

As @Aurora and @LukePark said, the phrase "don't roll your own" exists for a reason. If you are doing this for your own learning and never plan to use it, then cool, but otherwise please use PBKDF2 to derive the key from a passphrase, and please use AES for the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is relatively trivial to break this cipher without the key or passphrase being sent, given enough intercepted traffic.